# Being Flexbox element as flexbox container too

Tags: html, css, flexbox

// Excuse my beginner's English

Hello!
Can i implement follow construction:

```
<div class="flex-container-1">
    <div class="flex-element-1 flex-container-2">
        <div class="flex-element-2">...</div>
        <div class="flex-element-2">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-element-1 flex-container-2">
        <div class="flex-element-2">...</div>
        <div class="flex-element-2">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My simple attempt:

```
.flex-container-1, .flex-container-2 {
    display: flex;
}
.flex-element-1, .flex-element-2 {
    flex: auto;
}
```

... is not correct.

Making this more flatten is not way for me, because i need grouping container.

Have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, could you please elaborate?

Comment: @HashemQolami, i want place flexbox into the flexbox as immediate child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you want to do, but in your example you only use `display: flex` on the container. Flex box has more possibilities, and you can read about them here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

For example if you use `flex-direction: column` on the `flex-container-2` you will get something like this:

```css
.flex-container-1, .flex-container-2 {
    display: flex;
    
}
.flex-container-2 {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-element-1, .flex-element-2 {
    flex: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container-1">
    <div class="flex-element-1 flex-container-2">
        <div class="flex-element-2">1...</div>
        <div class="flex-element-2">1...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-element-1 flex-container-2">
        <div class="flex-element-2">2...</div>
        <div class="flex-element-2">2...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! That, i can use flexbox without `display:flexbox`. Thank you, so much!